# Using ng-remote-validate directive along with Angular-xeditable directive

Tags: angularjs, x-editable, remote-validation

I am trying to do remote validation using ng-remote-validate directive on an editable textbox, created using Angular-xeditable directive.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" editable-text="vm.product.name" onaftersave="vm.updateProduct()"
ng-remote-validate="{{vm.pageUrl}}Product/IsUnique" dummy="{{vm.dummyName}}"
ng-remote-method="GET">{{vm.product.name || 'not set'}}</a>
```

But Console window is showing the following error:

> Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [editableText, ngRemoteValidate] asking for new/isolated scope on: <a href="#" editable-text="vm.product.name" onaftersave="vm.updateProduct()" ng-remote-validate="{{vm.pageUrl}}Product/IsUnique" dummy="{{vm.dummyName}}" ng-remote-method="GET">
>
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$compile/multidir?p0=editableText&p1=&p2=ngRemoteValidate&p3=&p4=new%2Fisolated

Is it possible to use ng-remote-validate directive along with Angular-xeditable directive? If yes, please help me to solve this.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add 'e'  before your angular property

```html
<a href="#" editable-text="vm.product.name" onaftersave="vm.updateProduct()"
e-ng-remote-validate="{{vm.pageUrl}}Product/IsUnique" e-dummy="{{vm.dummyName}}"
e-ng-remote-method="GET">{{vm.product.name || 'not set'}}</a>
```

Comment: This guided me to the right direction and I was able to solve the issue. Thanks..!